# How can use PHP header() function inside PayPal Javascript code

Tags: javascript, php, paypal

I am trying to integrate Paypal with my website and now am facing problem to actually handle different messages sent by paypal like success, failed, cancelled and all

I am pasting a small part of the paypal JS code where it handles the messages below

```
onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {
            return actions.payment.execute()
              .then(function (res2) {
                // Show a confirmation message to the buyer
                console.log(res2);
                console.log(res2.transactions[0].related_resources[0].sale.state);
                //state codes - completed, partially_refunded, pending, refunded, denied
                if(res2.transactions[0].related_resources[0].sale.state == 'completed'){

            //  alert("Payment received for the invoice number" + res2.transactions[0].invoice_number); 

                }   
              });
          },
          onCancel: function (data, actions) {
            // Show a cancel page or return to cart

            alert("Payment  cancelled");
          },
           onError: function (err) {
            // Show an error page here, when an error occurs

            alert("Payment  error");
          }
```

Now what I want is, Whenever the payment is "completed" i want php to append to URL something like

```
order-placed.php?completed&invoice=$invoiceNumber
```

I tried placing PHP inside the JS code just above the Paypal alert messages but when i tried loading the page, It says "This page isn’t working localhost redirected you too many times." Can anyone guide me on this please? Is there an alternative way in which i can handle different payment status messages? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use PHP header function inside the javascript code because that will not work.you can redirect your page via below code in javascript.

```
location.href = 'http://youdomain.com/order-placed.php?completed&invoice=<?php echo $invoiceNumber ?>';
```

Hope this helps you.